# Обработка HTML формы Golang Gin

Tags: html, golang, post, form

Как получить данные и записать их в структуру, а также сделать редирект на главную страницу, помогите пожалуйста?

```
HTML FORM:
    
    <form action="/api/register" method="post" name="registerForm">
            <span class="fontawesome-user"></span><input name="username" type="text" required placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"> 
            <span class="fontawesome-envelope-alt"></span><input name="email" type="text" id="email" required placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="fontawesome-lock"></span><input name="password" type="password"  id="password" required placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Continue" name="continue" title="Continue">
        </form>
    
Golang Gin Router:
    action := router.Group("/action")
        {
            action.GET("/registration", func(context *gin.Context) {
                context.HTML(http.StatusOK, "registration.html", gin.H{"title": "registration"})
            })
            action.GET("/authorization", func(context *gin.Context) {
                context.HTML(http.StatusOK, "authorization.html", gin.H{"title": "authorization"})
            })
        }
        api := router.Group("/api")
        {
            api.POST("/token", controllers.GenerateToken)
            api.POST("/register", controllers.RegisterUser)
    
            secured := api.Group("/secured").Use(middlewares.Auth())
            {
                secured.GET("/ping", controllers.Ping)
            }
        }
    
User.go Form:
    type User struct {
        gorm.Model
        Username string `json:"username" gorm:"unique" form:"username"`
        Email    string `json:"email" gorm:"unique" form:"email"`
        Password string `json:"password" form:"password"`
    }
```

Comment: А вопрос есть какой-то?

Comment: поправил, забыл вставить сам вопрос

Comment: Вопроса по прежнему не видно